# How can I change LimeSurvey Radio Buttons styles?

Tags: php, css, colors, limesurvey

Sorry of my lack of knowledge but I installed limesurvey 1.9 to my server.
http://ankaracity.com/wingo/index.php?sid=41381

I need to put each answers to colorfulled boxes.
And need to make black of selected answer color.
So is it possible to do it with css?
And how do I?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css codes to remove radio circle and make it highlighted (when selected) (I still don't know how can I do it for each answer, anyway)

```
/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {

    margin:-2px;
*/    padding: 4px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #2f5376;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
   background-image: none;
    background-color:#ff0000;
color:#ffffff;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```